# Header "/usr/include/sqlite3.h" not found

Tags: sqlite.swift

Just installed SQLite.swift from cocoapods in my Xcode project and I get an error when trying to build stating Header "/usr/include/sqlite3.h" not found. Therefore I get an error stating could not build Objective-C module 'SQLite3'.

Am I just doing something wrong or is there an issue here?

Comment: This looks like a bug with the latest release. I'll file an issue and we'll try to get 0.9.1 out to address the issue.

Comment: Please try locking to the `module-map-path` branch (see https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/319).

Comment: i realize that the module-map-path branch doesn't exist any more but i see that you have already pushed 0.9.1. I've tested it and it works! Thank you for the very quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a note to echo the above comments that this should be fixed now.

The latest 0.9.2 should also work ok and be slightly more compatible, even for Swift 2.2 (as well as Carthage, CocoaPods or manual install).